# Update products using csv import but dont update url_key

Tags: magento2, product, import, catalog, import-products

I have products on magento 2.4.0 now when I use product import (Add/Update & also replace) to update product data, it throws below error

```
Url key: 'this-is-product-url-key' was already generated for an item with the SKU: 'this-is-sku'. You need to specify the unique URL key manually in row(s):
```

In short I dont want to update url_key

I have tried adding field url_key with data in it(url_key which is already generated previously)

Also tried removing url_key field completely which is then throwing below error

```
The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists
```

& also tried adding field url_key with blank data

Can anyone please help looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the url_key column from your CSV file and try the import again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already havent added url_key  column in my csv, it still throws error

Comment: roger that, i thought you had a full csv

Answer (score 0):

The check, that triggers this validation is in `\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::isNeedToValidateUrlKey`:

```
    /**
     * Check if need to validate url key.
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isNeedToValidateUrlKey($rowData)
    {
        if (!empty($rowData[self::COL_SKU]) && empty($rowData[self::URL_KEY])
            && $this->getBehavior() === Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND
            && $this->isSkuExist($rowData[self::COL_SKU])) {
            return false;
        }

        return (!empty($rowData[self::URL_KEY]) || !empty($rowData[self::COL_NAME]))
            && (empty($rowData[self::COL_VISIBILITY])
                || $rowData[self::COL_VISIBILITY]
                !== (string)Visibility::getOptionArray()[Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE]);
    }
```

So, if your CSV file contains `name` field the check will be triggered if item is visible or there is no `visibility` column.

To bypass this validation you could follow the first condition: CSV file should contain `sku` column, import behaviour should be `append` and product should be existed.

If you don't need to update product's `name` attribute try to remove this field from CSV file. This should help as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am bit confused - SKU field is already there on CSV with values in it, should I now remove name field ? Visibility field is also not added on CSV

Comment: updated comment with clarification

Comment: I mean, In my csv SKU column is already there with its values & Name column field with its data is already there, I havent added visibility column, do you want me to add visibility column or you want me to remove name column?

Comment: if you don't want to update `name` attribute feel free to remove it from CSV file. You could add `visibility` column, but to bypass the validation value should be `Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE`: 1. This will hide updated product from frontend

Comment: 1st thing removing name coloum from csv thrown error= name cant be blank & 2nd I dont want to hide product from frontend, I want to update products but its throwing error which I mentioned in my question